# Solving the Same Riddle Twice

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> My prefix tries to scout out the concealed
>   My suffix reacts to an electric field
>   My infix has a rodent, but not in the middle
>   .. But isn't there a better way to pose this riddle?
>
> My prefix is the red circle button
>   My suffix does sometimes contain mutton
>   My infix kicks the ball off to a teammate
>   Yup. These newer choices sure do seem great.

Comment: Great idea! $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: If one of the answers have solved this riddle, make sure to give it a big $\color{green}{\checkmark}$ :D

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Are you

> RECONSIDERATION?

My prefix tries to scout out the concealed

> Doing RECON(naissance) on something.

My suffix reacts to an electric field

> An ION does that.

My infix has a rodent, but not in the middle

> RAT is in the word, but not in the middle. @ManyPinkHats notes that "not in the middle" could mean on the SIDE, giving an infix of SIDE RAT. Thanks very much for your input!! :D

.. But isn't there a better way to pose this riddle?

> Yeah, sure, let's do it! (We have here RECON + SIDE RAT + ION). As @tyobrien points out, upon RECONSIDERATION of the first riddle, @Bass decided to create a second riddle! Thanks for the clever usage of the word!! :D

My prefix is the red circle button

> The RECord button.

My suffix does sometimes contain mutton

> Mutton was sometimes found in the WW2 RATIONing supplies.

My infix kicks the ball off to a team mate

> As long as they're ONSIDE.

Yup. These newer choices sure do seem great.

> REC + ONSIDE + RATION!

Comment: Nice work! I was pretty close...

Comment: I think the first riddle's infix should be ROT13(FVQR ENG), which explains both the second half of the line and includes the letters that would be missing between the prefix and infix.

Comment: Thanks, @ManyPinkHats! I have added your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: @ManyPinkHats nice!

Comment: You gave the first riddle some reconsideration and decided to redo it.

Comment: @tyobrien That's really clever!! I'm going to add your suggestion as well, I love it :D

Answer (score 9):

You are

> recoveration

My prefix tries to scout out the concealed

> recover

My suffix reacts to an electric field

> ion

My infix has a rodent, but not in the middle

> rat

My prefix is the red circle button

> rec (as in record)

My suffix does sometimes contain mutton

> a ration (of food)

My infix kicks the ball off to a team mate

> kicks it "over"

Comment: Ooh this is another good answer, I like it!! (+1) from me!

Comment: I had '-ration' but couldn't get the start.. I was thinking it was going to be a synonym of repetition like iteration or something :) Good job +1

Comment: I thought about iteration too :p To the point of googling "it/ite red circle button".

Comment: I actually had rec- and recon- first! I didn't consider rationing until I put rat-ion together ;P I like your infix explanation as well!!

Comment: Am I really the first to point out that your solution is not actually a word?  While the wordplay seems fairly reasonable, shouldn't it be a red flag that the solution is not actually a word?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I never let that get in the way of a potential solutation.